# Is it really worth it?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that was made by another developer, and I've been assigned the job to add extra functionality, although this question isn't about one application, it's about a language.

In C#, I find myself running across this probably around 50 times a day, I need to grab a value from a method and store it to a variable, or I need to store a variable, or even if I just need to hard code a variable to something.

Do I go with my head or my heart? My head says store it in a variable incase I need to use it more than once in the future, but then my heart says lets be lazy and just add it to the if check, instead of calling the variable, let me give you an example...

**Example 1:**

```
var name = SomeClass.GetName();    
if (name.Contains("something"))
{
    // do something 
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
if (SomeClass.GetName().Contains("something"))
{
    // do something 
}
```

I guess what I am asking is, does it have any sort of advantage? Or does it not really matter?

Am I using memory by storing these? especially if I'm storing hundreds across a solution in all different types of methods?

Is it worth just using it inside the if directly for an advantage, or should I just have a variable just in case? Can anyone explain the difference? If there is any that is.

I'm talking about if I only ever use the variable once, so don't worry about the "having to change in multiple locations" issue, although if anyone does want to go into that aswell, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I had coded them inside the question, I'll fix that now.

Comment: This is about a micro-optimization and the answer is: It doesn't matter. Use whatever you find easiest to read.

Comment: What if `GetName` needs a trip to the DB or a search through a collection or something? In those cases if you need it multiple times there are good arguments to store it.

Comment: I tend to start with the second example and then go to the first if I find mysefl using the variable again. As you get better at coding, you will be able to identify situations where each is more appropriate so you will have to go back and refactor less.

Comment: You should rename your question, the title is worthless as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there will not be any notable advantages in performance wise as well as in memory-wise. But when we look into the following scenarios storing return values have some advantages.

- The calling method(`SomeClass.GetName()` in this case) may return `null`

Consider that the `SomeClass.GetName()` may return `null` subject to some conditions, then `null.Contains()` will definitely throw `NullReferenceException` [*This will be same in both examples that you listed*] in such case you can do something like the following:

```
var name = SomeClass.GetName();    
if (name!= null && name.Contains("something"))
{
    // do something 
}
```

- Need to use the return value more than one time:

Here you are using the return value only for checking the `.Contains("something")`, consider that you wanted to use the return value later in the calling method, then it's always better to store the value in a local variable instead for calling the method repeatedly. *If it's only for checking `contains` then change the return type to boolean and finish the job within the method*

Comment: Why not just `if (SomeClass.GetName()?.Contains("something") ?? false)`?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: Yep possible only if the c# version supports null conditional operator. And what to do in this case: I want to use the return value of `SomeClass.GetName()` if `SomeClass.GetName().Contains("something")` is true

Comment: Yes, correct and true. Although that's a worry that appears not to be part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this question about this line of code:

```
var name = SomeClass.GetName();
```

How expensive is `GetName()` method? Is it going over the internet and downloading a file from somewhere and it takes seconds to minutes to download the file? Or is it doing some crazy computation that takes a few seconds to minutes. Or is it getting data from the database? These answers will help you decide if you should store it in a variable and then reuse the variable.

The next question even if the above answers were "Na! It is pretty quick and does nothing fancy" is to ask yourself this: "How many places in the current class are you making this call? 1? 10? 100? If your boss comes one day and says, "You know that method `GetName()`, well we are not going to use it anymore. We will use another method named `GetName2()`". How long will it take? Well imagine if you need to make the changes in 100 different places.

So my point is simple: ***It all depends***.